# use dplyr to create dummy variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do the folowing using `dplyr`:

Suppose you have the `data.frame` `y` and you want to create a new variable based on values of `var1`

```
y <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100))
y$var2 <- 0
y$var2[y$var1 > 0.5] <- 1
```

Is it possible to do this using `dplyr`'s `mutate` and `filter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `mutate`:

```
> y <- data.frame(var1 = (-2):2)
> y %>% mutate(var2 = as.numeric(var1 > 0.5))
  var1 var2
1   -2    0
2   -1    0
3    0    0
4    1    1
5    2    1
```

**Update:** dplyr now uses `%>%` in place of `%.%`

Comment: What if var1 has missing values?

Comment: If there are NAs in var1 the dummy will also be NA. you can use `mutate(var2 = ifelse(is.na(var1),0,ifelse(var1>0.5,1,0)))`, which would assign 0 to NAs.